# Trouble filling an empty matrix in python

Tags: python

I have an array that was generated from records that contain [key, character]

I have a function that creates an empty matrix whose dimensions are determined by the size of the array and the width of the array. I need to populate this list using the characters from the first array. Right now when I compile this I just get **None**. Is there any way I can accomplish this different

```
def createArray(size):
    return [None] * size

def createMatrix(rows,cols):
    m = createArray(rows)
    for i in range(rows):
        m[i] = createArray(cols)
    return m

def fillMatrix(matrix, array):
    rows = len(matrix)
    cols = len(matrix[0])

    arrSpot = 0
    for r in range(0,rows,1):
        for c in range(0, cols, 1):
            matrix[r][c] = array[arrSpot][1]
            arrSpot += 1
    return
```

Comment: What are you calling? as of now, its just function definitions...

Comment: Anything obvious you do with this—like `a=createArray(16); m=createMatrix(4, 4); fillMatrix(m, a)`—is just going to raise a `TypeError`, because you're expecting each element of the array to be subscriptable, and they aren't. The only thing you could do that won't raise is to fill a 0-row matrix, or pass something that wasn't made with `createArray` as your array (e.g., a (row*col) x 2-or-more matrix would work…). If you want us to debug your code, you have to show us your actual code.

Comment: Also, the only code you have to fill in arrays is `createArray`, which puts `None` in each value. So, however you get this to work, presumably `fillMatrix` is going to be filling a matrix with the values of an array that has nothing but `None` values, so… why are you surprised that you end up with nothing but `None` values?

Comment: Did you really want to increment `arrSpot` every element? It looks as if it ought to be incremented every row only, unless I misunderstood the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just forgot to give fillMatrix a return value.

Comment: No, `fillMatrix` mutates the matrix in-place, so it probably _should_ return `None`, as it does.

Answer (score 0):

A fairly simple way to do this would be to append rows as you go to a list. So, something like this:

```
def create_matrix(rows, cols):
  matrix = []
  for i in range(rows):
    row = [0]*cols
    matrix.append(row)
  return matrix
```

I would typically just use [numpy](http://www.numpy.org/) for this. If you have numpy, then you can just do

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.zeros((rows,cols))
```

(Note that the input to np.zeros is a tuple, not two arguments.)

Answer (score 0):

```
dimension1 = int(input("Give the dimension of the row: "))
dimension2 = int(input("Give the dimension of the column: "))
matrix = [[0 for i in range(dimension1)] for j in range(dimension2)]
for y in range(dimension2):
    for x in range(dimension1):
        matrix[y][x] = int(input("next value starting from (0,0) to (0,1) to at 
        last(dimension1,dimension2) : "))
```